# Which stats are the best predictors of model sucess in real time?

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, time-series, quant-trading-strategies, statistical-finance

What are the best predictors of real time model success in quantitative trading, i.e. # of transactions, length of backtest, StdDev, Skewness, Excess Kurtosis etc
and what are the numerical values of the best predictors?

Comment: I don't know. But when you have 30 years of data and thousands of transactions like you do, that is probably enough data. I would be more concerned about omissions or biases in your backtest and would want to have the system development reviewed by someone I trust.

Comment: Out-of-sample testing through a variety of different trading environments may be one useful indicator.  Though this could give false results depending on how you train your model before those test periods.  I refuse to call anything a "best predictor" because...well, you'll see :)